# How to connect two websites from single database which uploads in different domains

Tags: php, mysql

I have two domains like

1. xyz
2. abc

In xyz I have admin folder and my main database is also uploaded in xyz. Now I want to access some data from xyz database table. How could I do this please help me.

Comment: how could i permitted ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect xyz database remotely at the abc server.If your database is mysql then you can refer below link on How to Connect to the MySQL Database Remotely.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

```
Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database

Host name = (use the xyz server IP address)
Database name = (xyz server database name)
Database username = (xyz database username)
Database password = (the password you entered for that database user on xyz)
MySQL Connection Port = 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `xyz` site has IP 127.0.0.1 (i know its local host, but just an example) and site `abc` has IP 127.0.0.2.

You have to give access in the database of site xyz that IP 127.0.0.2 can access the database.

On site abc you will need the IP 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. e.g.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","password","db");
```