# Connecting 2 mysql table (users)

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help to connect the 2 mysql table (users). Like I created 2website both 2 different dynamic website but I redirected them on each other. So If any user register on 1 it should be registered on both so he/she don't need to signup again and again. Both dynamic website are hosted on same domain but 2 different mysql. But I want just users table to be common.

It will be great help you guys help me.

Thank You

I don't have any good idea how I'll do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28629896/2943403

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways. You need create **one** database (one table `users`) and connect to it from your dynamic web-sites.

Change your code to look like:

```
$mysqliNew = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "here_database_users"); // init connection (at the start of the script)
```

At the right place use new variable `$mysqliNew`:

```
$mysqliNew->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1");
```

Comment: Thanks I got new idea to work on it. Got more ways to solve this.